# How to sum list of pandas dataframes by with respect to given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list of pandas dataframes with two columns, basically class and value:

df1:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 10 |
| John | 20 |

df2:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 30 |
| Bob | 40 |

There might be same "Names" in different dataframes, there might be no same "Names", and list contains over 100 dataframes. But in each dataframe all "Names" are unique.

What I need is to iterate over all dataframes and create one big one, where presented all values from "Names" and their total sums of "Count" from all the dataframes, so like:

result:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 50 |
| John | 20 |
| Mike | 30 |

Bob's data is summed, others are not, as they are only present once. Is there efficient way once there are many dataframes?

Comment: do a merge of the two DFs and add their count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do `pd.concat` then `groupby`:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs) # where dfs is a list of dataframes
```

then you can do

```
gp = df.groupby(['Name'])['Count'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following (assuming you have ,more data that only conatined in one dataframe use `fill_value=0` to still provide value..:

```
df1.set_index('Name').add(df2.set_index('Name'), fill_value=0).reset_index()

>>> Name    Count
0   Bob     50.0
1   John    20.0
2   Mike    30.0
```